# Adjusting a price through a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

So, I have an array of Objects (from an enum) added to a JList. Said Jlist has a ListSelectionListener. The Jlist is default so you can select multiple items (there's only 2 though) I currently have it setup like so (there are brackets, I just removed them):

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
double price = 0;
if (selectedObject == Enum.object1) 
  price += Enum.object1.getPrice();
else if (selectedObject == Enum.object2) 
  price += Enum.object2.getPrice();
else if (selectedObject == Enum.object1 && selectedObject == Enum.object2) 
  price += Enum.object1.getPrice();
  price += Enum.object2.getPrice();
else 
 price -= Enum.object1.getPrice();
 price -= Enum.object2.getPrice();
```

It does not accurately remove the price. It will just continuously add and then occasionally remove.

Comment: `else if (selectedObject == Enum.object1 && selectedObject == Enum.object2) ` is impossible - you need to look at ALL the selected items

Comment: @MadProgrammer That helped, but it's still not resolved. The issue is definitely in the subtracting part.

Comment: Actually, it's not, it's all about starting from scratch.  One piece of information that `ListSelectionListener` isn't giving you is weather the items was selected to deselected, so you can't simply "add" or "subtract" elements, instead, you start at `0` and loop through all the selected items adding in their price to generate a total

Comment: I attempted to use a loop and it did not work either. I saw something about mouse events, would that be the correct solution?

Comment: Can’t say it would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is, `ListSelectionListener` isn't going to provide you information about whether an item is been selected or deselected.  This means that you are forced to start with a value of `0` and loop through the currently selected items and calculate a new tally from scratch, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Test {

    enum Item {
        PEARS(100.0),
        APPLES(25.0),
        ICECREAME(225.30);

        private double price;

        private Item(double price) {        
            this.price = price;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JLabel tally = new JLabel("0");
                DefaultListModel<Item> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
                model.addElement(Item.PEARS);
                model.addElement(Item.APPLES);
                model.addElement(Item.ICECREAME);
                JList<Item> listOfItems = new JList<>(model);
                listOfItems.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        double price = 0;
                        for (Item item : listOfItems.getSelectedValuesList()) {
                            price += item.getPrice();
                        }
                        tally.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price));
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(listOfItems));
                frame.add(tally, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true); 
            }
        });
    }

}
```

> saw something about mouse events, would that be the correct solution?

No, why?  Because the selection can be changed via the keyboard or programmatically

Comment: 200 IQ genius thank you so much. You are a hero and I understand now.